# Update Second Table from Access Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am working for the first time with Access and VBA. I have two tables (`Vh` and `Tr`) and I have a form based upon the `Tr` table.

Within the `Tr` table there is a Vh_Id field (and visa versa for the `Vh` table) that I am trying to update. On the `Edit Tr` form I have a drop down consisting of all the IDs from the `Vh` table and I have some SQL setup to run once this dropdown is changed. I get the dialog that tells me that 1 row will be affected, and despite saying yes, I never see a change made in the `Vh` table.

How can I get the following code to actually update the chosen record from the `Vh` table to update it's `Tr_Id` field with the current record?

```
Dim command As String
command = "UPDATE Vh SET Tr_Id = " + Me.Tr_Id + " WHERE PK = " + Str(Me.Vh_Id)
DoCmd.RunSQL (command)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'vice versa' - why would Vh table have a field for Tr_Id field? Tables cannot have two-way relationship.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim command As String
command = "UPDATE Vh SET Tr_Id = " & Me.Tr_Id & " WHERE Vh_Id = " & Me.Vh_Id
DoCmd.RunSQL (command)
```

edit: Looks like the `Str()` function was the culprit so better not to use it in your where clause.  According to the `Str()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6a1sx7(v=vs.90).aspx), 'When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number'.

Comment: I still have the same problem. Access tells me that `You are about to update 1 row(s)` and when I click yes and open the `Vh` table, nothing is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to fix this, I think you need first to stop and have a serious think about your table relationships.  It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve with your cross referencing IDs between Vh and Tr is some sort of One-to-One relationship.  That is to say that each record in Vh can have only one equivalent in Tr and vice-versa.  This is perfectly acceptable, but what you are trying with your code, will lead you straight into problems.  Do you want to allow, what I call, orphans?  That is to say, is it possible that some records in Vh have no equivalent in Tr and vice versa?

To illustrate my point suppose you have five records in each.  PKs 1 to 5 and Cross referencing IDs 1 to 5 in both.  Now suppose you have your Edit form on Tr and you want to change the Vh_Id of the first record in Tr to 5 (the last record in Vh).  Having made the change in Tr, there are now two records in Tr (PKs 1 and 5) pointing to the same record in Vh (PK 5).  If you now update (as you are suggesting) Vh such that PK 5 has Tr_ID 1, then you are left with the following problems.  Two records in Tr point to the same record in Vh (PK 5), but Vh PK 5 only points back to one of them (Tr PK 1).  Vh PK 1 is still pointing to TR_ID 1, but Tr PK 1 is pointing to Vh_ID 5.  There is no entry in Tr that points to Vh PK 1.  I.e. your cross referencing system is completely broken as a result of just one edit.

Please have a think about what you really want to do, come back here and we'll try to get it fixed for you.

Comment: I am trying to achieve a 1 to 1 relationship. Having an orphans wouldn't be a killer, but I would love to see that not happen. Such as if Vh 5 changed from Tr_Id 2 to Tr_Id 3, then Tr 2's Vh_Id field would become null and Tr 3 would be updated.

Comment: In defining your tables within access, have you added this relationship?

Comment: So here is a problem straight away.  You cannot set a field to null, because that would break the relationship.

Comment: Normally when people create a one-to-one relationship it is because they want to split a table effectively in two.  Maybe there are very many columns, maybe the columns are regularly required only as groups. When they do this, the one thing they do not want is that the user can mix the IDs.  That makes no sense.  I am still at a loss to understand the thinking behind what you want to do.  (I am going to be away for c. 2 hours)